# Angular reactive form returning data:image/png;base64 in network console instead of hitting the login API

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using Angular material 8.0.1 in Angular 9 where I'm building a login form using Angular reactive forms. Now the problem is when I enter the user details and try to hit the login API, instead of hitting the /login path, it's hitting a path of base64 image of an exclamation mark, it is supposed to return an XHR type request not a PNG type. The image it's returning is below:

> data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAGYSURBVEhL5ZSvTsNQFMbXZGICMYGYmJhAQIJAICYQPAACiSDB8AiICQQJT4CqQEwgJvYASAQCiZiYmJhAIBATCARJy+9rTsldd8sKu1M0+dLb057v6/lbq/2rK0mS/TRNj9cWNAKPYIJII7gIxCcQ51cvqID+GIEX8ASG4B1bK5gIZFeQfoJdEXOfgX4QAQg7kH2A65yQ87lyxb27sggkAzAuFhbbg1K2kgCkB1bVwyIR9m2L7PRPIhDUIXgGtyKw575yz3lTNs6X4JXnjV+LKM/m3MydnTbtOKIjtz6VhCBq4vSm3ncdrD2lk0VgUXSVKjVDJXJzijW1RQdsU7F77He8u68koNZTz8Oz5yGa6J3H3lZ0xYgXBK2QymlWWA+RWnYhskLBv2vmE+hBMCtbA7KX5drWyRT/2JsqZ2IvfB9Y4bWDNMFbJRFmC9E74SoS0CqulwjkC0+5bpcV1CZ8NMej4pjy0U+doDQsGyo1hzVJttIjhQ7GnBtRFN1UarUlH8F3xict+HY07rEzoUGPlWcjRFRr4/gChZgc3ZL2d8oAAAAASUVORK5CYII=

When I'm making the form by ngModel it's working out just fine but in case of reactive forms, it's not working out and hitting this png image.

Login.component.html:

```
<div class="my-account sec-padding">
  <div class="container">
      <mat-card fxLayout="row" fxLayout.lt-sm="column" fxLayoutAlign="start start"  class="p-0">
          <div class="my-account-wrap p-0" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.lt-sm="column" fxLayoutAlign="start start" >
              <div class="login-wrapper pr-50" fxFlex="50" fxFlex.gt-md="50" fxFlex.md="50">
                  <div class="title">
                    <h3>Login</h3></div>
                  <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="signinFunction()" fxLayout="row wrap">
                    <div  fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-sm="100" class="px-1" ngClass.sm="mt-1" ngClass.xs="mt-1">
                        <mat-form-field class="w-100">
                            <input matInput formControlName="email" class="form-control"  placeholder="Username or email address (required)" required>
                            <mat-error *ngIf="email?.invalid">Please enter a valid message</mat-error>
                          </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                    <div  fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-sm="100" class="px-1" ngClass.sm="mt-1" ngClass.xs="mt-1">
                        <mat-form-field class="w-100">
                            <input matInput formControlName="password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password (required)" required>
                            <mat-error *ngIf="password?.invalid">Please enter a valid message</mat-error>
                          </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                    <div class="button-wrap" fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-sm="100" class="px-1" ngClass.sm="mt-1" ngClass.xs="mt-1">
                        <button class="btn-project" mat-raised-button color="accent" type="submit">Log in</button></div></form></div><app-signup></app-signup></div></mat-card></div></div>
```

login.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ToastrManager } from 'ng6-toastr-notifications';
import { ProductService } from '../../client/services/product.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.sass']
})
export class AdminLoginComponent implements OnInit {
  loginForm: FormGroup; public email: any; public password: any;
  constructor(private productService: ProductService, private toastr: ToastrManager, private router: Router,private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required],
    })}
public signinFunction(): any {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('email', this.loginForm.get('email').value);
  formData.append('password', this.loginForm.get('password').value);
if(!this.email){
  this.toastr.warningToastr('Enter your email', 'Oops!');
} else if(!this.password){
  this.toastr.warningToastr('Enter your password', 'Oops!');
} else {
  let data = {
    email: this.email,
    password: this.password }
  this.productService.signinFunction(data).subscribe((apiResponse) =>{
    if(apiResponse.status === 200){
      this.productService.setUserInfoInLocalStorage(apiResponse.data.userDetails);
      this.toastr.successToastr('Logged in Successfully', 'Success!');
    } else {
      this.toastr.errorToastr('Some Error Occured', 'Oops!');
    }},(err) =>{
    this.toastr.errorToastr('Some Error Occured', 'Oops!')})}}}
```

ProductService.service.ts:

```
  public signinFunction(formData): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.post(http://localhost:4000/api/v1/login, formData);
  }
```

[image]

Comment: do you forget the quotes in this.httpClient.post? NOTE: See that is you don't indicate to Angular you want the full request, you has no a "status" in response, see https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

Comment: no I did put the quotes around it's a typo I did here..the problem is that when I use ngModule instead of reactive forms, it's working out fine

Comment: why not use `let data = {email: this.loginForm.value.email,  password: this.loginForm.value.password }`? I don't see what is this.email and this.password

Comment: still getting same result..can't really figure out what's the issue happening here with reactive forms